# Concerning the ring of all real valued functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, ideals, banach-algebras, bounded-variation

Let $B[a,b]$ the ring of all real valued functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ . What is the cardinality of $B[a,b]$ ? How does the maximal ideals of $B[a,b]$ look like ? How does the prime ideals of $B[a,b]$ look like ? Is this ring isomorphic with $C[a,b]$ ? What is the structure of nil-radical of this ring ? And please can someone provide some texts or online references where I can read about this ring ? Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: The nil radical is very obviously zero for any (pointwise multiplied) ring of real functions.

Comment: When I google the question, I'm led to a review of Gelfand's *Commutative normed rings* with this line:" The last chapter of the second part---the most specialized of all the chapters---is devoted to the investigation of the ring of functions of bounded variation on a line with multiplication defined as convolution, including the complete description of the maximal ideals of this ring." That may be the wrong operation for you, though.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes, I was talking about pointwise multiplication ; thanks for the information though

Comment: It could also be the case that the reviewer misinterpreted the operation and that it really is pointwise.

Comment: $B[a,b]$ is clearly not isomorphic to $C[a,b]$: the former one has lots of nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: @rschwieb: that idempotent observation , very neat , thanks !

Comment: It is nearly impossible to fail to see why. Where do you get stuck while checking?

Comment: A function of bounded variation is continuous at all but countably many points, so we can describe such a function with a countable sequence of real numbers (the value at every rational, plus the value at every point of discontinuity). This implies $B[a,b]$ has continuum cardinality.

Answer (score 3):

An elementary proof that $BV$ is a ring / Banach algebra was given by Russell:

> A. M. Russell, A commutative Banach algebra of functions of bounded variation, *Amer. Math. Monthly*. **87** (1980), 39–40.

As already mentioned in the comments, $BV$ contains non-trivial idempotent so is not isomorphic to $C[0,1]$ as ring. Observe that $BV$ is non-separable, hence is not isomorphic to $C[0,1]$ as a Banach space either.

$BV$ was studied as a Banach algebra in this seminal paper by Newman.

> S. E. Newman, [Measure algebras and functions of bounded variation on idempotent semigroups](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-163-00/S0002-9947-1972-0308686-4/S0002-9947-1972-0308686-4.pdf), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **163** (1972), 189–205.